# How to create a clickable html table with php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I just tried creating a clickable table to show more information by clicking on a table row.

This is my code for the table creation:

```php
while ($data= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td style='text-align: center;'>" . $data['number'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $data['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

How can I create a click event on every specific table row which calls a function with the unique id of the entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's lots of ways you can go about doing this. 
The simplest way here would be to add an onclick listener to the row

```
while ($data= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        echo "<tr onclick=myfunction() id=". $data['unique_identifier'].">";
        echo "<td style='text-align: center;'>" . $data['number'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $datensatz['name'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

And myfunction sends an ajax request or you preload the data and just display the data. The id serves as either mysql where clause or as a getter in case the data is preloaded

Comment: But if I set the unique_id_for_row, all rows have the same number, am I right?

Comment: Sorry my explanation was short. You use $data['number'] or some other identifier and because it is looping through the $data it will be different for each one

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($data= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td style='text-align: center;'>" . $data['number'] . "</td>";        echo "<td>" . $datensatz['name'] . "</td>"; ?>
    <td> 
       <a href="yourprog.php?number=<? echo $data['number'] ?>&name=<? echo $data['name'] ?>" ></a>
    </td><?
    echo "</tr>";
    }
```